# error cuando lanzo el comando git branch en movaxterm

Tags: git

No me ejecuta el comando `git branch` en mobaxterm.

Me da el siguiente error

```
/bin/busybox.exe less -R: /bin/busybox.exe: No such file or directory
```

Tampoco me ejecuta otros comandos como

```
git log --graph --topo-order --decorate --oneline --all
```

Me da el mismo error siempre. Se ve que está buscando las funciones `git log` y `git branch` en busybox.exe, pero no se encuentran ahí.

Creo que la solucion está en modificar la configuración del bash: 
    ~/.bashrc, ~/bash_profile, /etc/bashrc, /etc/profile
[Descrpción del uso de los archivos](https://elpuig.xeill.net/Members/rborrell/articles/los-archivos-bashrc-bash_profile-etc-bashrc-etc-profile-los-archivos-bashrc-bash_profile-etc-bashrc-etc-profile-cual-utilizar)

Comment: Tal ves te pueda servir este post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36822720/git-error-cant-execute-git-log-git-diff-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: He intentado la opcion de establecer vim con el comando "git config --global core.pager 'vim -'" no me funcionaba. Luego he eliminado en el .gitconfig el pager y tampoco.